# PBI DAX como puedo crear dos columnas que contengan una los valores INT y la otra los valores VARCHAR de otra columna que tiene estos valores juntos

Tags: powerbi, dax

tengo una tabla como la siguiente

```
Nombre_columna | Valor_columna 
columna 1      | 1
columna 1      | cuchillo
columna 2      | 3
columna 2      | tenedor
columna 3      | 45
columna 3      | cuchara
```

necesito dos columnas resultantes de la siguiente manera

```
Is INT     | Is VARCHAR 
1          | cuchillo
3          | tenedor
45         | cuchara
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien cual es la distribución de los datos en tu columna pero si todos tienen el mismo formato, por ejemplo la siguiente tabla que tiene todos los Strings del lado izquierdo y tienen los Int del lado derecho separados por un espacio, podes hacer lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde el editor de consultas podes escoger la opción **Dividir Columnas** y especificar el delimitador, en mi caso un espacio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]